# Flutter Desktop: how to hide a window (and keep the process alive)?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, flutter, flutter-desktop

Is it possible to programmatically hide or close a window (not minimize), but still keep the process alive? This is similar to the `hide()`/`show()` methods in Qt and this is the standard approach in order to minimize the app to the tray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package [window_manager](https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager) [suggested by lijy91](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69023833/1125233) didn't work out for me, because it did not work with Wayland under Fedora 36. It works perfectly on X11.

For now, I have decided to use [bitsdojo_window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window) combined with [system_tray](https://pub.dev/packages/system_tray). It is definitely more than "just a window manager", but it works on my systems including Windows and MacOS.

A perfect example is already given on the [example page of system_tray](https://pub.dev/packages/system_tray/example):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:bitsdojo_window/bitsdojo_window.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide MenuItem;
import 'package:system_tray/system_tray.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());

  doWhenWindowReady(() {
    final win = appWindow;
    const initialSize = Size(600, 450);
    win.minSize = initialSize;
    win.size = initialSize;
    win.alignment = Alignment.center;
    win.title = "How to use system tray with Flutter";
    win.show();
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final SystemTray _systemTray = SystemTray();
  final AppWindow _appWindow = AppWindow();

  Timer? _timer;
  bool _toogleTrayIcon = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initSystemTray();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  Future<void> initSystemTray() async {
    String path =
        Platform.isWindows ? 'assets/app_icon.ico' : 'assets/app_icon.png';

    List<String> iconList = ['darts_icon', 'gift_icon'];

    final menu = [
      MenuItem(label: 'Show', onClicked: _appWindow.show),
      MenuItem(label: 'Hide', onClicked: _appWindow.hide),
      MenuItem(
        label: 'Start flash tray icon',
        onClicked: () {
          debugPrint("Start flash tray icon");

          _timer ??= Timer.periodic(
            const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            (timer) {
              _toogleTrayIcon = !_toogleTrayIcon;
              _systemTray.setImage(_toogleTrayIcon ? "" : path);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
      MenuItem(
        label: 'Stop flash tray icon',
        onClicked: () {
          debugPrint("Stop flash tray icon");

          _timer?.cancel();
          _timer = null;

          _systemTray.setImage(path);
        },
      ),
      MenuSeparator(),
      SubMenu(
        label: "Test API",
        children: [
          SubMenu(
            label: "setSystemTrayInfo",
            children: [
              MenuItem(
                label: 'setTitle',
                onClicked: () {
                  final String text = WordPair.random().asPascalCase;
                  debugPrint("click 'setTitle' : $text");
                  _systemTray.setTitle(text);
                },
              ),
              MenuItem(
                label: 'setImage',
                onClicked: () {
                  String iconName = iconList[Random().nextInt(iconList.length)];
                  String path = Platform.isWindows
                      ? 'assets/$iconName.ico'
                      : 'assets/$iconName.png';

                  debugPrint("click 'setImage' : $path");
                  _systemTray.setImage(path);
                },
              ),
              MenuItem(
                label: 'setToolTip',
                onClicked: () {
                  final String text = WordPair.random().asPascalCase;
                  debugPrint("click 'setToolTip' : $text");
                  _systemTray.setToolTip(text);
                },
              ),
              MenuItem(
                label: 'getTitle [macOS]',
                onClicked: () async {
                  String title = await _systemTray.getTitle();
                  debugPrint("click 'getTitle' : $title");
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          MenuItem(label: 'disabled Item', enabled: false),
        ],
      ),
      MenuSeparator(),
      MenuItem(
        label: 'Exit',
        onClicked: _appWindow.close,
      ),
    ];

    // We first init the systray menu and then add the menu entries
    await _systemTray.initSystemTray(
      title: "system tray",
      iconPath: path,
      toolTip: "How to use system tray with Flutter",
    );

    await _systemTray.setContextMenu(menu);

    // handle system tray event
    _systemTray.registerSystemTrayEventHandler((eventName) {
      debugPrint("eventName: $eventName");
      if (eventName == "leftMouseDown") {
      } else if (eventName == "leftMouseUp") {
        _appWindow.show();
      } else if (eventName == "rightMouseDown") {
      } else if (eventName == "rightMouseUp") {
        _systemTray.popUpContextMenu();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: WindowBorder(
          color: const Color(0xFF805306),
          width: 1,
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              LeftSide(),
              RightSide(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const backgroundStartColor = Color(0xFFFFD500);
const backgroundEndColor = Color(0xFFF6A00C);

class LeftSide extends StatelessWidget {
  const LeftSide({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      child: Container(
        color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            WindowTitleBarBox(
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [backgroundStartColor, backgroundEndColor],
                      stops: [0.0, 1.0]),
                ),
                child: MoveWindow(),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RightSide extends StatelessWidget {
  const RightSide({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            WindowTitleBarBox(
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [backgroundStartColor, backgroundEndColor],
                      stops: [0.0, 1.0]),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: MoveWindow(),
                    ),
                    const WindowButtons()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final buttonColors = WindowButtonColors(
    iconNormal: const Color(0xFF805306),
    mouseOver: const Color(0xFFF6A00C),
    mouseDown: const Color(0xFF805306),
    iconMouseOver: const Color(0xFF805306),
    iconMouseDown: const Color(0xFFFFD500));

final closeButtonColors = WindowButtonColors(
    mouseOver: const Color(0xFFD32F2F),
    mouseDown: const Color(0xFFB71C1C),
    iconNormal: const Color(0xFF805306),
    iconMouseOver: Colors.white);

class WindowButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  const WindowButtons({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        MinimizeWindowButton(colors: buttonColors),
        MaximizeWindowButton(colors: buttonColors),
        CloseWindowButton(colors: closeButtonColors),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`window_manager` is support `show` & `hide` window. you can try this.

https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no Flutter APIs for controlling windows from Dart code. You would need to write native code to hide the window for the platform(s) you are interested in, and call it from Dart via [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).